# Are the parts of Bullet That Can Kill The Past still obtainable after crafting it?

Tags: enter-the-gungeon

After giving all the Bullet That Can Kill The Past parts to the Blacksmith in the Forge, can i still loot the parts in my following runs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, once a part has been delivered, it no longer spawns.  In the case of parts that have their own rooms, those rooms will no longer show up on future runs.

Comment: The one exception seems to be the obsidian shell casing, which you can get after each Dragun kill. Of course, since the casing doesn't have any effect on its own, there's no real need to pick it up again.